# how to make a profile picture plugin for joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have made a website with joomla. Now I want users to add their own profile picture, so I use a plugin from mosets but it shows only the picture's name. I tried to modify that plugin but I could't. Here is my code:

```
jimport('joomla.image.image');
jimport('mosets.profilepicture.profilepicture');
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$profilepicture = new ProfilePicture($user->get('id'));

if( $profilepicture->exists() )
{
    echo '<img src="'.$profilepicture->getURL().'" alt="'.$user->get('name').'" />';
}
```

using this code i can show profile picture but it shows a joomla error message spce.

Comment: any one master persion is there

Comment: if it shows only picture name on your page, then i guess path to image is not correct, check page source. and what error do you get?

Comment: hi Marko thanks for response please help if you can make a plugin for joomla which can add a profile picture in user profile then please help me it is very impotant for me

Answer (score 0):

Use a profile plugin with a media field. Copy and modify the example plugin in the core distribution.

Comment: if you know then tell me how because i am not getting how can i do that i can make a user plugin with my costume fields but i don't know how can add media field pls pls help me

Comment: You got to look in the profile plugin xml file. Change the type, name, labels, description etc to the desired values. The type for a media field is media - and it will have the options labelled on the link here: http://docs.joomla.org/Media_form_field_type

Comment: heyyyyyyyy i have don what i wanted to do just follow this article [link](http://www.mangluoiweb.com/2012/04/add-avatar-imageprofile-picture-for.html)